# Thread inside another thread in a while loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, while-loop

I'm pretty new to C++ and I'm experimenting with threads right now. 
I'm trying to create a thread inside a thread under a while loop. But I don't think it seems to be working.
Presently my code looks like this:

```
#include <>
std::vector<pthread_t> outer_thread, inner_thread;

    void *inner_thread(void *ptr)
    {
      string data1;
      data1 = *(reinterpret_cast<string*>(ptr));
      cout << "inner thread started " << data1;

/* do something */
      cout << "inner thread stopped " << data1;

pthread_exit(NULL);
  return 0;


    }

    void *outer_thread(void *ptr )
    {
cout << "out thread started" << endl;
//cout << ptr << endl;
//cout << *(reinterpret_cast<string*>(ptr)) << endl;
string data;
data = *(reinterpret_cast<string*>(ptr));


      string str3;
while (getline(data,str3))
{
      cout << "out thread started" << endl;


pthread_t in_thread;
in_vec.push_back(str3);
                int create_thread2 = pthread_create(&in_thread, NULL, &inner_thread, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&(in_vec.at(j))));
                inner_thread.push_back(in_thread);


      if (create_thread2 != 0) 
        cout << "Error : Thread";


      j++;

      cout << "out thread ends " << j << create_thread2 << endl ;

    }
         for (int k = 0; k < j ; k++)

{
pthread_join(inner_thread.at(k),NULL) ;
}

pthread_exit(NULL);
  return 0;

}   
    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      int i = 0;
      while (getline(gin,str))
      {
 string str1;
                pthread_t out_thread;
                cout << "str1" << str1 << endl;
now_vec.push_back(str1);
int create_thread = pthread_create(&out_thread, NULL, &outer_thread, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&(now_vec.at(i))));
                outer_thread.push_back(out_thread);
                if (create_thread != 0) cout << "Error : Thread" ;

        i++;
      }

for (int k = 0 ; k < i; k ++)
{
cout << i << endl;
//cout << "third thread " << outer_thread.at(1) << endl;
cout << outer_thread.at(k) << endl;
cout << "out out out" << endl;
pthread_join(outer_thread.at(k),NULL) ;
}


    }
```

I'm trying to read a file which contains the list of files that should be read. I want to read all these files simultaneously. 
All these files contain information and needs another set of threads to start another operation. So this also needs to be done simultaneously. 
That's the reason I have 2 sets of threads running.
Let me know If there is any faster and simpler way to do this?

It seems to wait till the inner thread finishes and then starts with the next iteration. I want the inner threads to run simultaneously inside the outer thread. May I know how to go about this?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. You're not returning values.

Comment: you have [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) *inside* the loop... that's why is waiting.

Comment: `pthread_t threads[i];` You're not allocating here correctly (`int i = 0;`) in the first iteration.

Comment: Lots of issues here. `pthread_t threads[i];` is size 0 on the first iteration, `&threads[i]` points past the end of the array, `j` is not declared anywhere, etc.

Comment: If I remove that, it doesnot seem to be working.

Comment: @jsantander answered your question. Your loop is blocking on `pthread_join()`.

Comment: Not to mention variable-length arrays are not standard C++.

Comment: ... and the fact that a thread *inside* a thread does not make sense. A (heavy) process contains one or more (light) processes (aka threads). These threads are created from different points in the code, but there's no relationship between the thread that executed the thread-creation request and the thread that gets spawned.

Comment: There are two while loops. I just want the process to be faster. So that there are many threads inside each outer thread. I might be wrong. Just wanted a simpler solution.

Comment: I'm trying to read a file. The file contains information of all the files that I have to read. So get those file names and read and perform the operation on each and every file. That 's reason I have a thread inside thread. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `pthread_create` and `pthread_join` operated on multiple threads at once?  If you want to create or join every thread in an array, you need to use a loop.

Answer (score 8):

Your view of the operation of threads is wrong. A thread does not operate within another thread. They are independent streams of execution within the same process and their coexistence is flat, not hierarchical.

Some simple rules to follow when working with multiple threads:

- Creating threads is expensive, so avoid creating and destroying them rapidly. It is best to create your threads once at the start of your application and assign them work to do as work becomes available.
- When doing computational work, avoid creating more threads than can simultaneously execute on your CPU. Any additional threads will cause excess context switches and slow down your application.
- Avoid the use of shared resources as often as possible, if a data structure must be shared between threads try and find a lock free implementation. If your shared resource is not available in a lock free implementation then use locks to protect it, but be very careful, improper use of locks can result in your application deadlocked or the performance of you application degrading to the serial execution case (as if there was only one thread).

In your particular case, if you want to speed up the processing of multiple files by processing them in parallel (and assuming the only task these threads need to achieve is the processing of these files), then a possible solution would look like:

1. Read in the list of files to operate on
2. Divide the list into sections (one section for each logical processor on you CPU).
3. Create your worker threads (one per logical processor) passing in their section of the file list (do not try to join with the thread in the same loop that creates it, this will block until the thread has finished executing causing your application to execute serially instead of in parallel, which is the case in the sample code you provided)

The worker threads can loop over their list of files, reading them one at a time and processing them.

In contrast to you proposed solution this one will not create a thread per file. Instead it will create as many threads as can run in parallel on your CPU avoiding the excessive context switching.

A primitive example of the above:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#define NUM_THREADS 4

std::vector<std::string> work_pool[NUM_THREADS];

void *worker_thread(void *args);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

    // Read list of files here, distribute them evenly amongst the work_pools

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, worker_thread, (void *)i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}

void *worker_thread(void *args)
{
    const int id = (int)args;
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;

    for (it = work_pool[id].begin(); it != work_pool[id].end(); it++) {
        // Read file and process it here
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I modified the script based on your suggestions. Not sure if that's what you meant but needed a feedback on the code

Comment: I modified the script but the value is not being passed correctly at all the places. Not sure what the problem might be!

Comment: The problem with this is, I can never be sure of the number of threads I require. The NUM_THREADS there can vary from 0 to 10 or 20 .

Comment: The number of threads should never exceed the number of logical processors on your CPU (for this kind of problem). If you have 4 cores and hyper threading then your CPU can run 8 threads simultaneously. If you create more threads than this you will slow things down instead of speeding things up. If you have a list of 400 files to process simply add 100 files names to each work_pool and then each worker thread will process them one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but among the many syntax errors that I hope come from simplying your code, this is what happens:

1. Main thread spawns a thread (1) and wait for it to finish (join)
2. (1) thread executes outer_thread and spawns another thread (2) and wait for it to finish (join)
3. (2) thread executes inner_thread and finish.
4. (2) gets joined and (1) thread is able to finish.
5. (1) gets joined and the main thread is able to go to the next iteration.
6. process starts again.

Note that you don't have any parallel execution, because your threads are waiting for other finish.

Note that throwing threads at a task is not the way to speed up.

Threads are a way of either:

- Better using your CPU resources (when you have multiple CPU resources... and only using as many threads as CPU resources you have)
- Simplifying the organization of your code by encapsulating requests as threads (but this kind of trick scale very badly)

Comment: How can I start a parallel execution in this case?

Comment: @user3309525 do not wait for one thread to finish to start the next...

Comment: I'm not sure how to declare the threads before the while loop as I'm not sure how many threads will be needed.