# Python How to run multiple functions every n seconds without interference

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium

So assume I'm trying to automate tasks on a webpage with selenium.

I have multiple buttons I have to click, which take me to different parts of the page where I have to run different functions to do different tasks. With each click of these buttons, when the corresponding tasks have been completed, a timer appears in the place of the button. When that timer runs out, I have to click that button again and run the corresponding function of tasks, then rinse and repeat.

Here is the code I've tried:

```
import selenium
import threading

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://example.com")

def foo1():
    button1 = driver.find_element_by_id("button1")
    button1.click()
    # do stuff
    timer = int(button1.text)
    threading.Timer(timer, foo1).start()

def foo2():
    button2 = driver.find_element_by_id("button2")
    button2.click()
    # do stuff
    timer = int(button2.text)
    threading.Timer(timer, foo2).start()

def foo3():
    button3 = driver.find_element_by_id("button3")
    button3.click()
    # do stuff
    timer = int(button3.text)
    threading.Timer(timer, foo3).start()

foo1()
foo2()
foo3()
```

Now, my problem with this is that, because there are multiple of these buttons, the scenario of one of the timers running out while another function is running can occur. This causes the script to click away without finishing the current sequence of tasks, thus terminating one of the threads.

I've tried using threading.Lock() objects but they didn't fix the issue. Do I have the wrong approach or am I just missing something here?

Comment: You should create and start the threads outside the function that you're defining them in currently

Comment: What did you try when using the Lock object? Did you place it before starting the new Timer?

Comment: @g2i I defined a Lock object in every function, acquired it at the start, and released it before defining the Timer objects

Comment: @AbhinavMathur could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Emrys added an answer for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the same structure of code by using a `Lock` object. However, you only have to define one `Lock` object and acquire/release it in every function, like this:

```python
import selenium
import threading

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://example.com")
lock = threading.Lock()

def foo1():
    lock.acquire()
    button1 = driver.find_element_by_id("button1")
    button1.click()
    # do stuff
    timer = int(button1.text)
    lock.release()
    threading.Timer(timer, foo1).start()

def foo2():
    lock.acquire()
    button2 = driver.find_element_by_id("button2")
    button2.click()
    # do stuff
    timer = int(button2.text)
    lock.release()
    threading.Timer(timer, foo2).start()

def foo3():
    lock.acquire()
    button3 = driver.find_element_by_id("button3")
    button3.click()
    # do stuff
    timer = int(button3.text)
    lock.release()
    threading.Timer(timer, foo3).start()

foo1()
foo2()
foo3()
```

By doing so, you ensure that your function is atomic. For instance, if `foo2` is called while `foo1` is executing, then `foo2` will be executed once `foo1` calls `lock.release()`.

Comment: Looks like one mutual `Lock` object did the trick mostly. My mistake when trying to use them was defining `Lock` objects for each individual function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The least painful solution to your problem is by using multiple webdriver objects, each of the objects in a different thread, and use a dictionary of the variables you want to be communicated.

```
import time
def foo():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://example.com")
    button = driver.find_element_by_id("button")
    while True:
        button.click()
        # do stuff
        timer = int(button.text)
        time.sleep(timer)
```

As far as I know the webdriver object is not thread-safe, so it is better to replicate it across mulitple threads , than using the same object over and over again in different threads. Also in your solution, you spawn different threads in every different loop iteration, which can have many repercussions. You can view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189298/thread-inside-another-thread-in-a-while-loop) post with a similar situation in C++

Comment: Well the problem with using multiple webdriver objects is that the site I'm working with also has a login system, and if I try to log in from a second instance, it logs me out of the first one

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You could share cookies between instances. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108933/python-multiple-instance-of-selenium-webdriver
So even if you use multiple instances, the site is like looking at only a single one

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, the thread initialization can be changed to solve the problem.

```
import selenium
import threading
import time 

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://example.com")

def foo1():
    button1 = driver.find_element_by_id("button1")
    button1.click()
    # do stuff
    timer = int(button1.text)
    time.sleep(timer)
    foo1()
    
def foo2():
    button2 = driver.find_element_by_id("button2")
    button2.click()
    # do stuff
    timer = int(button2.text)
    time.sleep(timer)
    foo2()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=foo1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=foo2)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```